# Keras ImageDataGenerator different images

Tags: python, keras

I'm having trouble with Keras's `ImageDataGenerator` for image augmentation. Right now, I'm trying to vertically flip the images in my training dataset. `X_batch` is my flipped image dataset and `X_train` is my original training dataset.

Can someone explain why the images in `X_batch` are in a different order than the images in `X_train`? `X_batch[0]` should be a flipped version of `X_train[0]`, but instead `X_batch[0]` is a flipped version of a different image in my dataset.

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)    

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(vertical_flip=True)
datagen.fit(X_train)

for X_batch, y_batch in datagen.flow(X_train, y_train):
    X_batch = X_batch.astype('uint8')

    plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
    plt.imshow(X_batch[0]) // flipped image

    plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
    plt.imshow(X_train[0]) // original image

    plt.show()
    break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Keras documentation](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/#flow) the `flow` method takes an argument called `shuffle` which if set to `True` (which is by default) shuffles the data and then apply the image transformations. You can set it to `False` if you don't like this behavior:

```py
for X_batch, y_batch in datagen.flow(X_train, y_train, shuffle=False):
    ...
```